# QODBC driver retrieve wrong bigint value from query while QMYSQL works fine

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, odbc, qt4

I've a mysql database with following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `scenario_configuration`
(
    `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `filename` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    `hash` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `state_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_scenario` PRIMARY KEY (`id` ASC)
)
;

INSERT INTO `scenario_configuration` (`id`, `filename`, `hash`, `state_id`) VALUES (uuid_to_bin('bfa993de-3a50-4e6c-8072-6e3283822142'), 'data6-4.scnx', '13283242987924624891', '3');
```

I want to retrieve the hash of a particular file with the following query:

```
select hash from scenario_configuration where filename = 'data6-4.scnx';
```

If I run the query from MySQL workbench, it works well and it returns `13283242987924624891` to me.

Then I run the same query from C++ using Qt 4.8 (yes, it's a legacy application unfortunately).

```
size_t Database::getScenarioHashFromName(const string& scenarioName) const {
  QSqlQuery query(m_database);
  const QString GetScenarioHashFromNameQuery{ "select hash from scenario_configuration where filename = '%1';" };
  size_t h{ 0 };
  query.prepare(GetScenarioHashFromNameQuery.arg(scenarioName.c_str()));
  bool ok = query.exec();
  if (ok) {
    int hashIndex = query.record().indexOf("hash");
    while (query.next()) {
      auto r = query.value(hashIndex).toULongLong();
      auto ss = query.value(hashIndex).toString().toStdString();
      h = static_cast<size_t>(r);
    }
  } else {
    auto error = query.lastError();
  }
  return h;
}
```

If I perform the query with the `QMYSQL` driver it works well, and `h` is `13283242987924624891`. But I need to use the `QODBC` driver, and the same query returns `9223372036854775807`, that in hexadecimal display is `0x7fffffffffffffff`. `ss` value is a std::string and it gives to me the same result, so it doesn't seem to be a conversion problem in `QVariant`.

Why I obtain different results with same code and query but different drivers, and how can I retrieve the correct value from the query using `QODBC`?

Comment: I would guess the odbc driver can not handle unsigned bigints correctly since the implementation in the qt sql odbc plugin looks fine. You should print out the real type of the QVariant with QVariant::type() to see what the driver really returns.

Comment: Check if NO_BIGINT option is enabled in the ODBC connection. If it is, disable it. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html

Comment: @Shadow It was already disabled unfortunately.

Comment: @chehrlic Unfortunately the type is `ULongLong`, that's the same type that I'm retrieving with the 'r' variable...